# Proving injectivity of $g(d)= d^2 + d + 1$ by contradiction

Tags: functions

Define the function $g:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ with $g(d)= d^2 + d + 1$

I started out by assuming that if two arbitrary elements of $\mathbb N$, $x$ and $y$,where $x>y$ without loss of generality, then $g(x)=g(y)$.
So 
\begin{align*}x^2 + x + 1 &= y^2 + y + 1\\
(x+1)(x-1)&=(y+1)(y-1)\\
x^2 + x &= y^2 + y.\end{align*}

I've tried rearranging the equation like this to try and find the contradiction. Am I on the right track? Any hints or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You may wish to have a look at our [basic MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to typeset math here.

Comment: Well... you would be if it weren't that $(x+1)(x-1) = x^2 - 1 \neq x^2 +x$... what about $x^2 +x = x (x+1)$ instead?

Comment: You can asume that $x\neq y$ and then you have $x+y=-1,$ which is imposible since $x,y\in\Bbb N$

Comment: A more efficient way would be to first write $g(d)$ as $g(d)=\left(d+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+\dfrac{3}{4}$

Comment: Then proceeding as you did.

Comment: @Carlos Where does $x+y = -1$ come from?

Comment: Suppose that $g(x)=g(y),$ then $x^2+x+1=y^2+y+1$ and hence $(x-y)(x+y)=-(x-y)$ @A.P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that since $x>y$ and $x,y\in \mathbb N$,  then $x^2 >y^2$,  so $x^2+x>y^2+y$,  in contradiction of your equality

Comment: So that would be sufficient to justify that the function is injective?

Comment: @user3699546 Injectivity means that different numbers have different images...

Answer (score 1):

A simpler proof uses the fact that $g$ is monotone increasing, that is $g(d) < g(d+1)$. There are many ways of showing that: you can calculate $g(d+1) - g(d) = 2d+2 > 0$, or you can calculate $g'(d) = 2d+1 > 0$.

Comment: Or say it is the sum of functions known to be increasing. That's what is implicitly used in @Alan's proof.